# iOS UIImagePickerController and TakePicture issue

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, image, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to make a simple app using Xcode and swift with a button. When the user presses the button a photo is taken, displayed on screen and saved in the camera roll of the iPad. I want to have a customized interface, therefore I don't want to use the standard imagePicker thing.

I've put some code trying to se the "takePicture" method but I can't manage to make it work :

```
var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController!
@IBAction func takePhoto(sender: UIButton) {
  imagePicker =  UIImagePickerController()
  imagePicker.delegate = self
  imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera
  imagePicker.cameraDevice = .Front
  imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = self.view
  imagePicker.showsCameraControls = false
  imagePicker.takePicture()
}
```

I guess that when executed the picture is taken and I would like to use the UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum function afterwards but I can't figure out how to access the picture.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController,
      didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])
{
     let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]
     //do something with the image or if you want the user to edit the image first
     let editedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage]
}
```

This method will be called after the photo is taken. You need to present the UIImagePickerController. If you want a custom UI, you can use the cameraOverlayView to provide one.